# Hooking dll into running process using loadappinit_dlls registry key

Tags: c++, .net, c, windows, dll

Currently I am working on a application in which I need to hook dll into running application. In order to achieve this goal, I have updated the `LoadAppInit_DLLs` registry key to 1 and `AppInit_DLLs` has been set to the location of the dll. 
This approach works fine as the application get opens the dll get injected into the process of that application.

However, this injection process not only inject the dll into the application that I am interested, but it injects it for all the applications that I am starting in windows operating system. How could I specify this inject to happen only for the application that I need it to inject and not for all the application. I am looking for a way to know from the dll that which application it is calling and then to decide whether to load it or ignore loading it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How could I specify this inject to happen only for the application that I need it to inject and not for all the application.

Using `AppInit_DLLs`, you can't.

[Working with the AppInit_DLLs registry value](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/197571/working-with-the-appinit-dlls-registry-value)

> All the DLLs that are specified in this value are loaded by each Microsoft Windows-based application that is running in the current log on session.

> I am looking for a way to know from the dll that which application it is calling

A DLL is loaded into the address space of a process. A DLL can call `GetModuleFileName(NULL)` to get the
full path and filename of the process it has been loaded into.

> and then to decide whether to load it or ignore loading it.

Normally, a DLL's `DllMain()` entry point allows the DLL to selectively abort loading by returning FALSE to the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` notification.  However, `AppInit_DLLs` specifies additional DLLs that are deemed required for successful app initialization, similar to static-linked DLLs, so it does not allow DLLs the luxury of selective loading.  If an `AppInit` DLL returns FALSE, the whole process is aborted.

You will have to manually hook the DLL into the target app yourself.  You can do that by either:

1. Using [`CreateRemoteThread()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682437.aspx) to call [`LoadLibrary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) from inside a specific process to load the DLL into that same process.  The DLL's entry point does not need to validate the loaded process, since the loading app has already done so when deciding which process to load the DLL into.

   This approach takes some setup, though.  You have to use [`VirtualAllocEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890.aspx) and [`WriteProcessMemory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx) to copy the DLL's full path string into the target process before you can then have the remote thread call `LoadLibrary()` with that path string as input.
2. Using [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) to install a global system-wide hook that is implemented inside the DLL, so the DLL gets loaded into every running process.

   The difference between this approach and using `AppInit_DLLs` is that this approach is handled dynamically after each process is running, and thus allows the DLL the luxury of selectively aborting its own loading without terminating each process it rejects.
3. Configuring the [Application Compatibility Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562082.aspx) to load your DLL into the specific app(s) you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

All DLLs, listed in the `LoadAppInit_DLLs` registry key will be loaded to the all processes, linked against `user32.dll`. If for some reason your dll is unable to load (for example - you had returned `FALSE` from the `DllMain` on `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`) the process will be terminated. Using `LoadAppInit_DLLs` even for the debugging purposes is messy and pretty dangerous. Perhaps you should choose another hooking mechanism, for example using `SetWindowsHookEx`

Comment: This is not true. Sure user32.dll's DLLMain() returned FALSE the app would terminate if it needed any imports from the DLL. It will not terminate if your AppInit DLL returns FALSE since nothing in the process is trying to import from your DLL.